# Branching to UFT API requests based on values in a data table

Tags: c#, api, qtp, hp-uft, branching-strategy

I have a "master" script in HP UFT 12.52 that runs tests for the gui side of or application and works fine. We want to use the same data table that drives the GUI tests on the web service.

The master uses an excel sheet to drive the values needed for each request. I can create an equivalent "on the fly" to point to the API calls behind a button. I have one column (APICall) which is the name of the soap request to send.

However, when I start the test, I can load the sheet into the API test holding the actions, but getting it to take the APICall value and branch to the appropriate action (named by API request) is proving impossible. The code exists in VBScript in the GUI actions. I don't see why it is so hard on the API side.

I'm also a junior C# programmer.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for the GUI VBScript and the API code that demonstrates your issue? You may have to resort to screenshots.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it in a combination of available UFT actions and custom code (in which the methods and properties are not well defined.)